# Arduino SD Card open file modes append / overwrite

Tags: c++, sd-card, sd

Running Arduine IDE `SD DataLogger Example`, my data gets appended to a txt file.

```
File dataFile = SD.open("datalog.txt", FILE_WRITE);
if (dataFile) {
  dataFile.println(dataString);
  dataFile.close();
}
```

Is there an explicit option to open the file in overwrite / append modes?

Comment: thanks for the edit @michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in [this library](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/SD/blob/master/src/SD.cpp), you see:

```
File SDClass::open(const char *filepath, uint8_t mode) {

    ...

    if ((mode & (O_APPEND | O_WRITE)) == (O_APPEND | O_WRITE)) {
```

So you can use all these mode combinations (e.g. O_CREATE, O_APPEND, O_WRITE).

Comment: answered the question as asked. UPVOTED & ACCEPTED  :)

Answer (score 4):

The Arduino SD library is an Arduino wrapper of old version of SdFat library (put into utility subfolder of the SD library). This SdFat library [has constants](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/SD/blob/b8a78d4b3bf970c776522b79f95c7cc4691ced3c/src/utility/SdFat.h#L52) like O_READ, O_WRITE, O_APPEND.

Arduino wrapper has constants

```
#define FILE_READ O_READ
#define FILE_WRITE (O_READ | O_WRITE | O_CREAT | O_APPEND)
```

You can use the SdFa library constants in the wrapper calls.

```
File dataFile = SD.open("datalog.txt", O_READ | O_WRITE | O_CREAT);
```

**Warning**: not all versions of SD library bundled in different board packages have O_APPEND in `#define FILE_WRITE`. Even in the Arduino SD library the O_APPEND was removed some time ago and then the change was reverted, because all dataloger examples used FILE_WRITE.

Comment: nice solution thanks!  UPVOTED

Answer (score 4):

You only need to open the file with `FILE_WRITE` and use `file.seek(EOF)` to go to de end of the file. After that you can write whatever you want that will be appended to the end of the file.

```
File outputFile = SD.open(LOG_FILE, FILE_WRITE);
outputFile.seek(EOF);
outputFile.println("Appended to the EOF");
```

Comment: perfect for day-to-day solutions, thanks!  UPVOTED